# Is there a way I can dance in Vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen people play Minecraft in YouTube videos and make their Minecraft character like, dance. They are able to lay down, move their shoulders side to side, sit down on the ground, etc. Is there a way I can do this in Vanilla Minecraft? Or do I have to install a mod? Also, I'm in Minecraft PC 1.12.2.

Sorry if this is unclear, if it does come out that way I'll change it ASAP.

Comment: All of it is either animation or good editing, there is no way to dance like that in vanilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Vanilla Minecraft.

You need to install mods like [Smart Moving](http://minecraftfive.com/smart-moving-mod/) which is compatible with your Minecraft version and provides various additional moving possibilities to Minecraft

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. That's part of some mods, but not of Minecraft Vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

In normal Minecraft it's not possible but if modded with [Emotes Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/2214387-emotes-dance-wave-facepalm-gangnam-style)
or with [Smart Moving](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/1274224-smart-moving) it is possible to do so.
I recommend the Emotes Mod.